# Android Yes/No/Cancel order in dialog

Tags: android, dialog

In my Android app (latest OS), I have a "do you want to save before you quit?" dialog and wondered whether the negative button should be "No" or "Cancel" for usability.

Obviously "Yes" is positive, but should I set "No" as negative and "Cancel" as neutral, or vice versa?

At the moment I have "Cancel" as neutral meaning my dialog displays in this order:

NO | CANCEL | YES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use

Save | Don't Save | Cancel

That is another format I have seen.

Comment: I will add that since most Android dialogs are in the format `Ok|Cancel`, the `Save|Don't Save|Cancel` dialog is what the user will be expecting.

Comment: Good deal, be sure to select as answer.

Comment: Good idea. I have changed the wording, but as the positive button is placed on the right, would it be better to have:
DON'T SAVE|CANCEL|SAVE
or...
CANCEL|DON'T SAVE|SAVE

Comment: I would have the CANCEL button on the outside with either direction you choose. It follows standards that people are used to.